# elasticsearch conditional field

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elastic-stack

I am new to elastic and I have a question about an action I want to perform on an index when creating it.

Is it possible that one of its fields is subject to only receiving a certain value and if it does not receive it, not paint anything?

I propose an analogy for this:
I have a field called flag and I only want it to support yellow, green and red . If this information is not received, mark a Null or do not paint anything. Is this possible?
Is there a property to achieve that?

This is at the elastic/kibana level

I hope to be clear. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Building a custom analyser for your field that will only map a regex of values provided, would suffice your requirement.
Custom Analysers ES Doclink : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using a painless script. Here is an example

a) Created a sample index with the following mapping

Created an index

```json
PUT /so73000363
```

Created a mapping

```json
PUT /so73000363/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "color": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Inserted 3 rows

```json
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so73000363",
                "_id": "TSr5BoIBCOifrGItOzcZ",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Watch",
                    "color": "yellow"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "so73000363",
                "_id": "Tir5BoIBCOifrGIthDdi",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Go",
                    "color": "green"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "so73000363",
                "_id": "TCr4BoIBCOifrGIt7zd-",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Stop",
                    "color": "red"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now lets say color can take only the following values Blue , Green, Red , Yellow

Lets try and perform the following upsert

```json
{
  "scripted_upsert":true,
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline" : "if (params.color.equals(\"blue\")||params.color.equals(\"green\")||params.color.equals(\"yellow\")||params.color.equals(\"red\")){ctx._source.color=params.color}",
    "params": {
      "color": "blue"
    }
  },
  "upsert" : {
    "name" : "Stop",
    "color" : "blue"
  }
}
```

if the value is blue this will get updated

```json
GET /so73000363/_source/TCr4BoIBCOifrGIt7zd-

{
    "name": "Stop",
    "color": "blue"
}
```

Try to update now with orange

````
{
  "scripted_upsert":true,
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline" : "if (params.color.equals(\"blue\")||params.color.equals(\"green\")||params.color.equals(\"yellow\")||params.color.equals(\"red\")){ctx._source.color=params.color}",
    "params": {
      "color": "orange"
    }
  },
  "upsert" : {
    "name" : "Stop",
    "color" : "orange"
  }
}```



Does not get updated as orange is not permitted.
````